# how do you pull in data from https in R using RCurl

Tags: r, curl

I am trying to use RCurl to perform rest call to an https site and pull down data like this:

```
library("httr")
library("XML")
library(RCurl)
setInternet2()
url<-c("https://dynatrace.com:8021/rest/management/reports/create/host_cpu_report?type=XML&format=XML+Export")
getURL(url, cainfo = "R/win-library/3.2/RCurl/dt.cer")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: R/win-library/3.2/RCurl/dt.cer
  CApath: none
```

I have https enable in RCurl as shown below:

```
curlVersion()$protocol 
 [1] "dict"   "file"   "ftp"    "ftps"   "gopher" "http"   "https"  "imap"   "imaps"  "ldap"   "pop3"   "pop3s"  "rtmp"   "rtsp"  
[15] "scp"    "sftp"   "smtp"   "smtps"  "telnet" "tftp"
```

Any ideas how can do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the specific REST API you are using or what kinds of calls you want to make, an example snippet might look something like this:

```
library(httr)
GET(content(
    url = "https://dynatrace.com:8021/rest/management/reports/create/host_cpu_report",
    add_headers(
        format = "XML+Export", 
        type = "XML", 
        token = "some access token"),
    body = "rockin'"
));
```

Add parameters and values using the `add_headers()` function, specify the URL, (presumably) attach some sort of access token and/or body to the request. `content()` converts the response into an R object (usually a list).

Comment: where do I get the access token? I think that's what my problem is.

Comment: You will have to read the documentation for the REST API you are trying to use. It might require a token, or it might not. Typically you register an app and generate the tokens yourself.

Comment: I am using getURL(url, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE), I still get the error. How do I go around the error (SSL: certificate subject name 'dynaTrace Server' does not match target host name example.com